# File directory error in JAR deployment

Tags: java, file, javafx, directory

I'm trying to get the names of all the files in a folder "clock" which is inside the working directory "src".

The snippet below works fine if I run it but when I build the JAR file and run that I get a null error.

```js
try {
  File directory = new File("src/clock/");
  File[] files = directory.listFiles();

  for (File f: files) {
    text.appendText(f.getName() + " ");
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  text.appendText(e.getMessage() + " ");
}
```

File structure:

[image]

**Update:** (I'm using the `ResourceAsStream` now but same problem runs fine, deployed JAR doesn't work)

```js
public void setImage() {

  List<String>fn;
  try {
    fn = getResourceFiles("/clock/graphics/backgrounds/");
    for (String s: fn) {
      text.appendText(s);

    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    label.setText(e.getMessage());
  }
}


private List<String>getResourceFiles(String path) throws IOException {
  List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<>();

  try (
    InputStream in = getResourceAsStream(path); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( in ))) {
    String resource;

    while ((resource = br.readLine()) != null) {
      filenames.add(resource);
    }
  }

  return filenames;
}

private InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resource) {
  final InputStream in = getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource);

  return in == null ? getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource) : in ;
}

private ClassLoader getContextClassLoader() {
  return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
}
```

Comment: does graphics folder has to be inside the jar ?

Comment: Yes, I want a single jar file

Answer (score 2):

That's because File searches in the

```
/path/to/your/application.jar
```

which File cant unzip to find the files in the specified path. It considers application.jar as a folder name and tries to read it.

Instead use

```
ClassLoader classLoader = YourClassName.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream sam = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

to read the file from ***resources*** folder of the project when you want your jar to read a file.

Comment: I updated my answer on seeing your project's folder structure. `getResourceAsStream()` reads a file from the resources. If you are taking it from a relative path like in your case use `InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/clock/graphics/backgrounds/example.xls")`;

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying this before but I want the names of all the files in the folder `/clock/graphics/backgrounds/*` in a `List` and not just one file, which is what I'm doing in the updated code but the JAR deployment doesn't work.